# How to import data from xls files with differents header

Tags: python, import, dataset, xls

I'm trying to collect data from multiples xls files.
The columns names and size change in each file.

For exemple I've a different header on each file.
Columns title are differents and can have speratated columns for the same datafield.

For exemple :
What I need : Reference, Name, Qt, Price, Amout

Exemple files

```
'A'+'B' = Reference ('1'/'1') / 'C' = Reference / 'D' = Quantity...
'A' = Reference ('1.1') / 'B' = Reference / 'C' = Nothing / 'D' = Quantity ...
'A' = Reference + Name / 'C' = Quantity...
```

What is the best practice to import dataset?
Python? Machine learning?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Wow!  This sounds like a really ugly design.  Ok, I am assuming at least SOME of the field names are the same, otherwise, you are not actually doing anything useful here.

Before.

[image]

After.

[image]

Run this VBA code in Excel to align the field names, as shown above.

```
Sub CompareRowDifferences1()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim i, LastColumn As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Transposed Fields")
LastColumn = sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column

With sht
    For i = 1 To LastColumn
        If StrComp(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(2, i), vbBinaryCompare) <> 0 Then
            .Cells(2, i).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            .Cells(2, i).Value2 = "NULL AS " & .Cells(1, i).Value2
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```